# Export data in excel sheet with background color to header row

Tags: angular

I want export data in Excel format with background to  header row .

I have used  Angular2Csv  to export file but i am not able to add background color to header.

```
let options = {
        fieldSeparator: ',',
        quoteStrings: '"',
        decimalseparator: '.',
        showLabels: true,
        title: 'Doctors Report',
        showTitle: true,
        headers: ['Fullname','Email','Phone No','],
      };

   new Angular2Csv(localArray, 'Title', options);
```

I want export array in excel/csv format with header background.

Comment: Csv and excel are different formats. You can't have any style in a csv since it is a plain text file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSV is comma-separated values and cannot have any kind of formats.

If you want to export your data to Excel sheet with filling rows background then use https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/. There is example in the issue on how to use the background color:

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/906

```
const COLORS = {
    'good': { patternType : 'solid', bgColor    : { rgb: 'C6EFCE' }, fgColor : { rgb: 'C6EFCE' }, fontColor : { rgb :'006100'} },
if (headers[C].style) {
   if (headers[C].style.color) {
        headers[C].style.fill = COLORS[headers[C].style.color];
        if (headers[C].style.font) {
           headers[C].style.font.color = COLORS[headers[C].style.color].fontColor;
        }
  }
  if (headers[C].style.repeat) {
    defaultStyle = headers[C].style;
  }
  if (defaultStyle) {
    ws[address].s = defaultStyle;       
  }else{
    ws[address].s = headers[C].style
  }
}else{
  ws[address].s = defaultStyle;
}
```

Comment: I am unable to find style property